Angular Material UI component for search bar?
I'm trying to build a generic search bar using Angular material ui. I don't see a 'search' component within the documents. Has anyone used material ui for a search component? Would using their input + autocomplete component be a good building block?

It depends on the needs of your search bar, the most simple approach would be just using:
search input + icon

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="search">
  <button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Search">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>


Thanks! I think this works for now. Do you have an example of what a search bar would look like with the auto-complete component?

This will require the following imports:
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'; import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'; import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
